# xamarin debug on iPad

Tags: ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I am developing a iOS app with xamarin. If I debug it in a physical machine (iPad) or a iPad simulator, it only shows a white screen. But it works if I debug with iPhone simulator.

What is the cause of the issue?

Thanks.

Updates : 
I found that it is due to the project only have an iPhone view. And it leads to another question - When I would like to change the width and height of content in iPad view, all views will change at the same time. Does it mean I need to create different storyboard for each screen size?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code in your StartUp controller page?

Answer (score 0):

The white screen issue is related to the zoom level on your simulator. On the Simulator, look at the Window menu and it will be either Zoom or Scale. Try setting Scale to 50%.